# @Autowired lateinit property '' has not been initialized

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, kotlin, vaadin

I'm trying to create a web project using Spring-boot + Vaadin and i want to use spring-data-jpa with hibernate to fetch the data from PostgreSQL database.

In my Vaadin's view i try to autowire my service class but i always get null and eror stack trace doesn't tell me why.

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   clientService has not been initialized    at
>   com.apache.vaadin.view.Index.getClientService(Index.kt:24)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.apache.vaadin.view.Index$readButton$1.buttonClick(Index.kt:40)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:211)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:174)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1029)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:370)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
>   ~[vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]  at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445)
>   [vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]   at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410)
>   [vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]   at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
>   [vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]   at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
>   [vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]   at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
>   [vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]   at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1464)
>   [vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]   at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:381)
>   [vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar:8.0.6]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

My config for database:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf("com.apache.vaadin.model"))
@ComponentScan(basePackages = arrayOf("com.apache.vaadin.model"))
open class DataSourceConfig {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var environment: Environment

    @Bean
    open fun entityManagerFactory(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        var entityManagerFactory: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()

        entityManagerFactory.apply {
            dataSource = dataSource()
            setPackagesToScan("com.apache.vaadin.model")

            var vendorAdapter: HibernateJpaVendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()

            vendorAdapter.apply {
                setGenerateDdl(true)
                setShowSql(true)
            }

            var properties: Properties = Properties()

            properties.apply {
                put("database.dialet", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect")
                put("database.globally_quoted_identifiers", "false")
                put("database.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true")
                put("database.show_sql", "true")
            }

            jpaVendorAdapter = vendorAdapter
            setJpaProperties(properties)
        }

        return entityManagerFactory
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    open fun dataSource(): DataSource {
        var source: ComboPooledDataSource = ComboPooledDataSource()

        source.apply {
            driverClass = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ignite"
            user = "postgres"
            password = "1111"
            acquireIncrement = 5
            idleConnectionTestPeriod = 60
            maxPoolSize = 20
            minPoolSize = 10
            initialPoolSize = 10
        }

        return source
    }

    @Bean
    open fun transactionManager() : PlatformTransactionManager {
        var manager: JpaTransactionManager = JpaTransactionManager()

        manager.apply {
            entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory().nativeEntityManagerFactory
        }

        return manager
    }

    @Bean
    open fun exceptionTranslator(): PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor  = PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor()
}
```

View and UI:

```
@SpringUI
@Title(value = "Apache")
class Navigator : UI() {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var viewProvider: SpringViewProvider

    init {
    }

    private val INDEX = ""

    override fun init(p0: VaadinRequest?) {
        navigator = Navigator(this, this)
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider)
        navigator.addView(INDEX, Index::class.java)
    }
}

@UIScope
@SpringView
open class Index : VerticalLayout(), View {
    private val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(Index::class.java)

    @Autowired
    lateinit var clientService: IClientService // <--- error is here

    init {
        var menuBar: MenuBar = MenuBar()
        var file = menuBar.addItem("File", null, null)
        file.addItem("Save", {_ -> logger.info("Save clicked")})
        file.addItem("Load", {_ -> logger.info("Load clicked")})
        file.addItem("Open", {_ -> logger.info("Open clicked")})
        file.addItem("Close", {_ -> logger.info("Close clicked")})

        var settings = menuBar.addItem("Settings", null, null)
        settings.addItem("DataBase", {_ -> logger.info("DataBase clicked")})

        addComponent(menuBar)

        var createButton: Button = Button("Create", { _ -> logger.info("Create clicked")})
        var readButton: Button = Button("Read", { _ -> logger.info(clientService.findAll())})
        var updateButton: Button = Button("Update", { _ -> logger.info("Update clicked")})
        var deleteButton: Button = Button("Delete", { _ -> logger.info("Delete clicked")})

        addComponent(createButton)
        addComponent(readButton)
        addComponent(updateButton)
        addComponent(deleteButton)
    }

    override fun enter(p0: ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent?) {
        Notification.show("Welcome to the main com.ignite.app.view")
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.apache.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ignite</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.0.6</vaadin.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.1.3-2</kotlin.version>
        <hibernate>5.2.9.Final</hibernate>
        <hibernate-validator>5.4.1.Final</hibernate-validator>
        <postgres>42.1.1</postgres>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgres}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Service:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface IClientService : CrudRepository<Client, Long>
@Service
class ClientService : IClientService {
    private val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientService::class.java)

    @Autowired
    lateinit var clientRepository: ClientRepository

    override fun delete(p0: Long?) {
        clientRepository.delete(p0)
    }

    override fun delete(p0: MutableIterable<Client>?) {
        clientRepository.delete(p0)
    }

    override fun delete(p0: Client?) {
        clientRepository.delete(p0)
    }

    override fun <S : Client?> save(p0: MutableIterable<S>?): MutableIterable<S> = clientRepository.save(p0)

    override fun <S : Client?> save(p0: S): S = clientRepository.save(p0)

    override fun findAll(p0: MutableIterable<Long>?): MutableIterable<Client> = clientRepository.findAll(p0)

    override fun findAll(): MutableIterable<Client> = clientRepository.findAll()

    override fun exists(p0: Long?): Boolean = clientRepository.exists(p0)

    override fun findOne(p0: Long?): Client = clientRepository.findOne(p0)

    override fun count(): Long = clientRepository.count()

    override fun deleteAll() {
        clientRepository.deleteAll()
    }
}
```

And repository:

```
@Repository
interface ClientRepository : CrudRepository<Client, Long>
```

Project compiles correctly, but when i try to get any data from my database i get this error. I also tried to create connection and queries manually and when i did it i didn't get any errors. Probably, the error in the datasource config but i don't see it.

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATED**
Solution:

```
@SpringUI
@Title(value = "Apache")
class Navigator : UI() {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var viewProvider: SpringViewProvider

    @Autowired
    lateinit var index: Index// <-

    private val INDEX = "index"

    override fun init(p0: VaadinRequest?) {
        navigator = Navigator(this, this)
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider)
        navigator.addView(INDEX, index) // <-
    }
}

@UIScope
@SpringView
@SpringComponent // <-
open class Index : VerticalLayout(), View {...}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because you try to access `clientService` in `init` block, you shouldn't do that, spring Dependency Injection occurs **after** the object was ready created. for example:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var clientService: IClientService

init{
    // v--- `clientService` is not injected by spring yet.
    clientService;
}
```

On the other hand, you should implements `InitializingBean` for the spring  component initialization, for example:

```
open class Index : VerticalLayout(), View, InitializingBean {

   @Autowired
   lateinit var clientService: IClientService

   override fun afterPropertiesSet(){
      //copy your init block code here
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this: `open class Index : VerticalLayout(), View, InitializingBean {

   @Autowired
   lateinit var clientService: IClientService

   override fun afterPropertiesSet(){
      //copy your init block code here
   }
}`      but i still get the same error. I also tried to inject my service by constructor injection. And finally, i tried to make additional function inside my Index.view where i call clientService.findAll, but again i get the same error: `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property clientService has not been initialized`

Comment: @NickRyan please see here: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-spring.html

Comment: Thank you! Finally, i works! I added annotation @SpringComponent and fixed Navigator class: `    @Autowired
    lateinit var viewProvider: SpringViewProvider

    @Autowired
    lateinit var index: Test

    private val INDEX = ""

    override fun init(p0: VaadinRequest?) {
        navigator = Navigator(this, this)
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider)
        navigator.addView(INDEX, index)
    }`   Probably, the problem was in "addView", because i sent the class definition, not the object and it tried to make new object and not to inject it.

Comment: @NickRyan Not at all. since your code is too large. I only can help you is that something you maybe have missed.